# Accessing df columns the wrong way causes empty vector, "no non-missing arguments to min/max, returning Inf/-Inf"

Tags: r, invalid-argument

I am a beginner on R, working on water quality data. PLease excuse my formatting mistakes. I am trying to run "nls" on my dataset. Running the script:

```
testingQModel<-nls(GR ~ GRm * (1-Kq/Q), data = testingQ, start = list(Kq = min(testingQ$Q), GRm = max(testingQ$GR)))
```

I get the following error:

Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

The dataset does not have NAs and is all numeric. I ran `range(testingQ, na.rm = TRUE)` also with `range(testingQ, na.rm = FALSE)` just to give it a try either way and it returned maximum and minimum values in dataset all right. I am not sure what else to try.
Look forward to a solution from someone! Thanks.

Comment: Try `range(testingQ$Q)` and `range(testingQ$GR)` to see if you still get a max and min that aren't `Inf` for your `start=` values. I suspect that is where the problem lies.

Comment: Is `testingQ` a data frame?

Comment: Yes, `testingQ` is the data frame consisting of two columns Q and GR. Ran the script `range(testingQ$Q)` and `range(testingQ$GR)`, both return `[1]  Inf -Inf`. I have no clue though why it would be like that. I assumed it would return max and min values in respective columns. I tried plugging in initial values for `GRm` and `Kq` too instead of `testingQ$GR` etc but it returned same warning messages. Those are the two parameters I am trying to calculate the values of. I would appreciate little more help!

Comment: @Learner - something is screwy with those two variables. They are likely empty if you are getting a range of `-Inf` to `Inf`. Try just `testingQ[,"Q"]` and see what it returns - also check `str(testingQ[,"Q"])` and `length(testingQ[,"Q"])` to see what the structure of the object is.

Comment: I ran all strings and each of them returned `Error in `[.data.frame`(testingQ, , "Q") : undefined columns selected` whereas a call for `Q` returns the column I defined as `Q`. Just for record, I defined Q as `Q<-testingQ[,1]` and `GR<-testingQ[,2]`. This is how I defined variables while working with different functions and it worked fine. Or maybe I was just lucky not to encounter this problem.

Comment: @thelatemail I am really stuck at this point in my analysis. I'd be greatly thankful for your help if you can!

Comment: @Learner - doing `Q <-testingQ[,1]` defines an object called `Q`, not a column inside your dataframe `testingQ`

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks a lot for pointing that out. It was such a stupid mistake. Not defining `Q` and `GR` that way solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing what you already seem to have solved and written in the comments:

- issue had nothing to do with nls or max
- issue was due to a bad access to a dataframe column, either bad syntax or else you had shadowed the definitions of Q, GR by defining variables with those names
- this then gave you an empty vector, which causes max to return Inf/-Inf
- solution was to fix the column access, or don't define the offending shadowing variables

My tip:
summary, max and min are a pain in R since they don't handle either NAs or completely empty inputs well.
So always either eyeball their input vector to double-check for sanity, or else assign their input to a variable and inspect that.

Comment: Yes, the problem had to do with wrongly defining Q and GR. Accessing columns directly by calling `testingQ$xyz` solved the problem.

Comment: @Learner: please either write up your answer then accept it, or accept this. It's good to close the loop for the sake of other people. (I was trying to solve a similar issue yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with smci, summary function like min are painful in R.

There is a solution for this in the hablar package that solves that min/max returns Inf when given an empty vector. The function s converts an empty vector (NULL) to NA.

**The problem**

```
min(NULL)

[1] Inf
Warning message:
In min(NULL) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

**Solution**

```
library(hablar)

min(s(NULL))
[1] NA
```

*disclaimer* I am biased for this solution since I authored the package.